# how to stop kernel threads preempting real time user space processes?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, scheduling, real-time

I created some processes in user space and tried to visualize its working in **kernelshark** with the trace recorded using **trace-cmd.** But kernel processes like the ones shown below are preempting my processes with real-time priority 98. I use the scheduler SCHED_FIFO for the processes that I have created in user space.

```
PID  PPID CLS PRI RTPRIO CMD

359     1 TS   19      - mount.ntfs /dev/disk/by-uuid/AC72763B72760A7A /root
366     2 TS   39      - [loop0]
```

What can I do to run my processes uninterrupted by these kind of kernel processes?

Comment: Generic Linux is a preemptive operating system and if you try to hack around that, you'll probably make the system unhappy. If you truly need real-time behavior, then you need a real [real-time OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). I suggest that you confirm that you truly need an RTOS before making the jump; there are many control and monitoring tasks that might have needed RTOS in the past but don't now because computers have gotten so fast.

Comment: Thank you. I'll go for some open source RTOS like RTAI soon if it gets too messy